# Detect touch on a drawn item in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cgcontext, uitouch

If i draw a circle using the `CGContext` ,is it possible to drag this circle using touch. Is there a way to check whether the touched area contains that drawn circle ?

I would like to create custom `UIControl` with either a circle or box shape.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is what i was expecting!

Comment: Then you can aceept the answr by clicking on the checkmark below it Thanku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is make the rect of that circle

```
CGRect myRect=CGRectMake(center.x-radius, cemter.y-radius, 2r, 2r);
```

and detect touch inside that rect by picking touch point as

```
CGPoint touch=[[touches anyObject]locationInView:self];
 if(CGRectContainsPoint(myRect,touch ))
{

//code here for true condition
 }
```